# How to get rid of the error coud not find function do() in R

Tags: r

I am doing bootstrap sampling.
I am using following code:

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rejection")
set.seed(7377)
B = do(1000)*mean(resample(c(rep(1,258),rep(0,352-258)),352))
```

But getting the following error:
Error in do(1000) : could not find function "do"

Comment: Does the function do() exist in your environment?

Comment: try `dplyr::do`

Comment: `dplyr::do(1000)` is going to throw an error.

Comment: I have attached dplyr package. But still getting the error.Error in UseMethod("do_") : 
  no applicable method for 'do_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Are you thinking of another computer software program? C++? Python? Julia? Stata? Maybe a `for` loop?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? dplyr::do(1000) is going to give you an error because `do()` isn't looking for a numeric argument.

Comment: And where does the `resample` function come from?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want **`replicate`**.

However, with `replace=FALSE`, the default for `gdata::resample`, your sample is always going to have the same mean. I suggest you add `replace=TRUE` to your `resample` command:

```
library(gdata)
set.seed(7377)

B <- replicate(1000, mean(resample(x=c(rep(1,258), rep(0,352-258)), size=352, replace=TRUE)))
B

#[1] 0.6988636 0.7386364 0.7187500 0.7698864 0.7329545 0.7244318
```